# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ln x^{2})^{2x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ln x^{2})^{2x}$

I felt the only approach to find the limits is taking log on both sides
$y=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ln x^{2})^{2x}$

$\ln y=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}2x \ln(\ln x^{2})$

Near $0$ , $\ln(\ln x^{2})$ will be $\ln(- \infty)$ . which is undefined.

So shall i conclude that the limit does not exist ?

Comment: Since $x \to 0$, it could be the case that $2x\ln (\ln x^2)$ goes to $0$ "faster" than it goes to $-\infty$ (in fact this is the case, since the limit exists)

Comment: @player3236 as a matter of fact the function $2x\log\log x^2$ is defined only when $|x|>1$.

Comment: @DDDD Let's start with a simpler question: What is your definition of $a^x$ for $a < 0, x > 0$?

Comment: As it is written, I think, the function is well defined for $|x|\geq 1$, and, for $|x|<1$ only when $2x$ is a rational number of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q$ odd. This does not prevent from taking the limit, since $0$ is a cluster point. 

A better definition for the function would be $\left[\left(\log x^2\right)^2\right]^x$.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in some comments, we have that

$$(\ln (x^{2}))^{2x}$$

is not a well defined expression as $x\to 0$ therefore in some context, as introductury calculus courses, we conclude suddenly that it is meaningless to consider the limit at that point.

Anyway, as observed from other users in the comments, when $x=\frac p q$ with $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ and $q$ odd we can algebrically evaluate the expression as $x\to 0$ and, within this restriction, the limit is $1$.

Indeed we have that

$$(\ln (x^{2}))^{2x}=\left|\ln (x^{2})\right|^{2x}=e^{2x \ln\left(\left|\ln (x^{2}\right)\right|)}$$

and by $x=\pm e^{-y}$ with $y \to \infty$

$$2x \ln\left(\left|\ln (x^{2}\right)\right|)=\pm \frac{2\ln (2y)}{e^y}\to 0$$

therefore

$$(\ln (x^{2}))^{2x}\to e^0=1$$

The problem with this more general approach is that when $2x=\frac p q$ with $p,q \in \mathbb Z$ both odds we have that

$$(\ln (x^{2}))^{2x}=-\left|\ln (x^{2})\right|^{2x}=-e^{2x \ln\left(\left|\ln (x^{2}\right)\right|)}$$

and the limit is $-1$ in this case.

Therefore to conclude we can say that the limit doesn't exists even for the rational restriction for $x$ in which the expression can be well defined.

Comment: How do you get the first equality? Which is wrong btw… use $x=1$ which gives you $0 = 1$

Comment: The equation is $(ln x^2)^{2x}$ . You have considered it $ln (x^2)^{2x}$

Comment: @DDDD. This is what you wrote. Add parentheses if you want to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have added appropriate parentheses

Comment: @DDDD Yes sorry I misread initially the question. Now fixed and added some detail more. The given expression is not well defined. In this case we don’t say that limit doesn’t exist but that it is completely meaningless to be considered since the expression in undefined.

Comment: I would say  the function  is defined, provided that the exponent is rational and with odd denominator. So $0$ is a cluster point of the domain and thus the limit is defined.

Comment: @dfnu Yes I agree with you. We can define a value for this case and then calculate a limit. The fact is that I don't know in which context the question has been posed and at an intoductury level we would say that the expression is not well defined. I'll add something on that. Thanks

Comment: @user it's also interesting to split the exponent $2x$ as I did in my comment to OP. In that case, too, the limit exists and it is equal to $1$, I believe

Comment: @dfnu I think we need $x=p/q$ with $q$ odd or $2x=p/q$ with $p$ even and $q$ odd otherwise again we have some problem with the sign.

Comment: @dfnu Yes the case with the exponent splitted leads to the same limit.

Comment: @user suppose $x=\frac16$. Then the function would return $-\sqrt[3]{2\log 6}$, am I correct?

Comment: @dfnu Yes using that $\sqrt[3]{-2\log 6}=-\sqrt[3]{2\log 6}$, that is assuming $\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$.

Comment: @user then the limit cannot be $1$ in this case.

Comment: @dfnu Indeed for that reason we need $x=p/q$ with $q$ odd such that the expression is positive otherwise the limit is $-1$. I think I need to be more precise on that.

Comment: @dfnu I think this is one of the more edited answers in the history! :)

Comment: @user :) well the situation was tricky enough

Answer (score 0):

Using
$$\big[\log ^2(x)\big]^{2 x}=\exp\Big[2x \log\Big(\big[\log ^2(x)\big] \Big]$$

For small values of $x$

$$\big[\log ^2(x)\big]^{2 x}=1+2 x \log \left(\log ^2(x)\right)+2 x^2 \log ^2\left(\log
   ^2(x)\right)+\cdots$$

Trying for $x=\frac 1{e^4}$ the lhs is $256^{\frac{1}{e^4}}\approx1.10690$ while the truncated expansion gives
$$1+\frac{2 \log ^2(16)}{e^8}+\frac{\log (256)}{e^4}\approx 1.10672$$

The limit is $1$.

**Edit**

If the problem is $\big[\log (x^2)\big]^{2 x}$, then, for small $x$
$$\big[\log (x^2)\big]^{2 x}=1+2 x \log ( \log (x^2))+2 x^2 \log ^2( \log (x^2))+\cdots$$ and the limit is $1$ again.

Comment: how did you expand $[log^2x]^{2x}$

Comment: The function was $log x^2$ , you have taken it has $log^2 x$

Comment: @DDDD. I asked you parentheses. $\log(x^2)$ of $\log^2(x)$ ?

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ln x^{2})^{2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\ln (x^{2}))^{2x}$